# ExtJs BufferStore not getting Filter

Tags: javascript, extjs6

I am using BufferStore and I am trying to filter store but bufferStore is not getting filter at all, 
  I am using following code

```
bufferStore.filter(
filterFn:function(record) {
    return record.get("myProperty").toLowerCase().indexOf(value)>-1;
}
```

});

It is not going inside filterFn even-though store has records,

Comment: The console tells you: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2278

Comment: BufferStore with remoteFilter true, this function not getting work? is that assumption true, if so then how to solve this problem ??